Python pyTelegramBotAPI, показать клавиатуру ReplyKeyboard обратно
Короче, у меня есть код, в котором в параметре types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup есть аргумент one_time_keyboard, который равен True, то есть:
cakeUp = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True, row_width=2, one_time_keyboard=True)

Можно ли как-то потом вернуть клавиатуру, или есть другой способ ее скрытия и отображения, подскажите, я новичок в этом
